# How to efficiently validate selects in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a few select drop downs in my application. But I have no way of validating the input on the backend. You could essentially change the values and submit it and it would work.

Take this for example:

```
  <%= f.select :gender, [['Male','male'],['Female','female']], required: "true" %>
```

how can I validate that what they submit is either 'male' or 'female' in the model?

Comment: you need a front-end js validation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[validates_inclusion_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of)**

In your model,write like this

```
 validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => %w(Male Female male female)
```